Any ideas?: Calculating wet-mass and burn altitude for a Mars landing, using a Python simulation
In this post, I will explain the problem, provide some detailed context, and finally explain what I am searching for (what my question is basically).
First of all, this should be quite a fun but challenging problem for anyone here...
For a python course we have been given an assignment to simulate a mars landing (from 20000 meters altitude).
This Mars landing will only be executed with reverse thrusters, so no parachutes involved.
I have almost completed this simulation, the last step is to determine at what altitude the thrusters must start firing, and also what the required propellant mass is to ensure we have a soft landing.
This is what my question is about (step 4 in the assignment description).
I am a first year aerospace engineering student, so my knowledge is quite limited, so I was hoping someone with more expertise could help me.
To provide the context for my question, this was the assignment and the python codes I have written so far: The assignment description provides some (vehicle) parameters and calculation assumptions.



Code for MarsLander.py
import math
from marsatm import marsatm, marsinit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("Please note that this simulation is calculation instense, depending on your computer this might take a while.")
while True:
    thrust_toggle = input("Please indicate whether you want to simulate thrusters (enter yes or no):").strip().lower()
    if thrust_toggle != 'yes' and thrust_toggle != 'no':
        print(" Please enter 'yes' or 'no' ")
        continue
    break

print("Calculating, please wait...")

data_array = marsinit()

# Defining Start conditions

#time
dt = 0.0001    #s
t = 0           #s

#dynamics
g0 = 3.711                   #m/s^2
gamma = math.radians(-20)    #rad

#velocities:
v0 = 262                            #m/s
vx = v0 * math.cos(gamma)           #m/s
vy = v0 * math.sin(gamma)           #m/s
v = math.sqrt(vx ** 2 + vy ** 2)    #m/s
vyref = -2                          #m/s

#position:
h_km = 20      # km
sx = 0      #m

#vehicle data:
kv = 0.05           #something
ve = 4400           #m/s
mdry = 699          #kg
mprop = 700         #kg
mwet = mdry + mprop         #kg
CdS = 4.92          #m^2. Drag coefficient * Area.

#lists to store data
ttab = [t]    #s

Gtab = [1]  #G-force list
acctab = [0]    # m/s^2     #absolute acceleration
vytab = [abs(vy)]  #m/s
vxtab = [abs(vx)]  #m/s
vtab = [v]  #m/s    #absolute velocity

htab = [h_km * 1000] #m     #altitude
sxtab = [sx]  #m     #horizontal displacement from t = 0

gammatab = [math.degrees(gamma)]    #attitude
Thrusttab = [0]     #thrust
dragtab = [0]       #drag
mdottab = [0]       #mass flow
mwettab = [mwet]    #total mass of the spacecraft

#Running the simulation in a loop.
while h_km >= 0:
    #update time
    t += dt      
    
    #calculate atmospheric data for given altitude.
    data_pack= marsatm(h_km, data_array)  
    temp, d, a = data_pack        
    rho = d

    #convert altitude to meters
    h_m = h_km * 1000    # m

    #update forces
    Fz = mwet * g0      
    drag = 0.5 * rho * (v ** 2) * CdS
    
    if thrust_toggle == "yes":
        deltavy = vyref - vy
        if mwet > mdry:
            mdot = (mwet * g0) / ve + kv * deltavy
            thrust = mdot * ve
        else:
            mdot = 0
            thrust = 0
    else:
        thrust = 0
        

    #calculate dynamics
    ax = ( math.cos (gamma + math.pi) * ( drag + thrust) ) / mwet
    ay = ( -Fz + math.sin (gamma + math.pi) * ( drag + thrust) ) / mwet
    acc = math.sqrt( ax ** 2 + ay ** 2 )
    Gforce = acc / 9.81     #G

    vy += ay * dt
    vx += ax * dt
    v = math.sqrt(vx ** 2 + vy ** 2)

    sx += vx * dt
    h_m += vy * dt

    gamma = math.atan(vy/vx)

    if thrust != 0:
        mwet -= mdot * dt
        mdottab.append(mdot)

    ttab.append(t)
    Gtab.append(Gforce)
    acctab.append(acc)
    vytab.append(abs(vy))
    vxtab.append(abs(vx))
    vtab.append(v)
    htab.append(h_m)
    sxtab.append(sx)
    gammatab.append(math.degrees(gamma))
    Thrusttab.append(thrust)
    dragtab.append(drag)
    mwettab.append(mwet)

    #convert altitude back to kilometers
    h_km = h_m / 1000    # km

plt.subplot(441)
plt.plot(sxtab, htab)
plt.title('trajectory')

plt.subplot(442)
plt.plot(vtab, htab)
plt.title('speed - alt')

plt.subplot(443)
plt.plot(ttab, gammatab)
plt.title('attitude')

plt.subplot(444)
plt.plot(ttab, Thrusttab)
plt.title('thrust - time')

plt.subplot(445)
plt.plot(ttab, htab)
plt.title('alt - time')

plt.subplot(446)
plt.plot(ttab, vtab)
plt.title('speed - time')

plt.subplot(447)
plt.plot(ttab, Gtab)
plt.title('G-Force')

plt.subplot(448)
plt.plot(ttab, dragtab)
plt.title('Drag - time')

plt.subplot(449)
plt.plot(ttab, vxtab)
plt.title('vx - time')

plt.subplot(4, 4, 10)
plt.plot(ttab, vytab)
plt.title('vy - time')


plt.subplot(4, 4, 11)
plt.plot(ttab, acctab)
plt.title('acceleration')

if thrust != 0:
    plt.subplot(4, 4, 12)
    plt.plot(ttab, mdottab)
    plt.title('mdot - time')

plt.subplot(4, 4, 13)
plt.plot(ttab, mwettab)
plt.title('mwet - time')

plt.show()
print("Simulation complete, you can view the results.") 

code for marsatm.py :
import numpy as np
import os

# Get the directory of the current script
marsatm_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

# Path to the marsatm file
marsatm_file_path = os.path.join(marsatm_dir, "marsatm.txt")


def marsinit():
    data_list = []  #create an empty list to store the data for each height
    with open(marsatm_file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            height, temp, rho, a = line.strip().split()     #extract the data from the file and assign relevant variables
            data_list.append([float(height), float(temp), float(rho), float(a)])    #store the variables as a list in the data list
    
    data_array = np.array(data_list)    #create a variable that defines the array, where each list in data_list becomes a row in the array (aka matrix)
    return data_array

if __name__ == '__main__':      #if the name of the code that is being run = marsatm, this section will run, otherwise it will be skipped.
    while True:                 #ensure that the input is valid
        h = int(input(f"height in m:")) / 1000
        if h > 150 or h < 0:
            print("Input is out of range, please enter a kilometre value between 0 and 150.")
            continue
        break
    
def marsatm (h, data_array):
    for i in range(len(data_array[:,0])):   #this loops iterates the process, of finding for which i (row in matrix) it is true, that h lies between two rows.
        if data_array[i,0] <= h <= data_array[i+1,0]:
            k = (h - data_array [ i,0 ]) / (data_array [ i + 1 , 0] - data_array [ i,0 ])   #computing the k value

            t = ( 1 - k ) * data_array [ i , 1 ] + k * data_array [ i + 1 , 1 ]   #computing the temperature
            d = ( 1 - k ) * data_array [ i , 2 ] + k * data_array [ i + 1 , 2 ]   #computing the density
            a = ( 1 - k ) * data_array [ i , 3 ] + k * data_array [ i + 1 , 3 ]   #computing the speed of sound
            return t, d, a  #return a tuple containing (t,d,a)


Results of simulation so far:

Now to the point, I have considered these options to solve the problem:

Just plugging in some values for the burn height and the propellant mass. And simulating until we find a desired result
Calculating Delta V's for the thrust, drag and gravity separately. And summing all these Delta V's and setting them equal to zero, to determine the burn height and prop mass.

The latter is what I am trying to do, and have gotten pretty far with it. I derived an equation for the DeltaV due to gravity, but deriving one for the drag is where I get stuck.
$$
\Delta V = \Delta V_{thrust} + \Delta V_{drag} - \Delta V_{gravity}
$$
where
$$
\Delta V_{thrust} = V_{exhaust} * ln(M_{wet}/M_{dry})
$$
$$
\Delta V_{gravity} = g_0 * (\frac{M_{wet}}{M_{wet}-M_{dry}} * t_{burn} + 1) + V_{@ thrust initiation}
$$
$$
\Delta V_{drag} = \frac{1}{M_{wet}-M_{dry}} * \ \int_{0}^{t_{burn}} (m_{wet} * \frac{Drag(t)}{mass(t)} + massflow(t) * \frac{Drag(t)}{mass(t)}) \ dt \
$$
These are the derivations for these equations, the first equation is of course the famous rocket equation. For the drag I went a bit further, but as you can see that was a horrible equation.
Please feel free to ask any questions about doubts in the derivations.


This system of equations is obviously very complicated. We want to determine a wet-mass and a burn time (which is directly related to the altitude at which the burn needs to start) that ensure a soft landing.
I could go on and on about the complexity, but this is how I see this problem proceeding:
If I was able to solve the equation for the drag, I would be able to express the Delta V as a function of wet mass (the burn time is a function of the wet-mass, as exhaust velocity is constant). Then I would be able to calculate the burn time corresponding to this and determine the corresponding altitude at which the thrusters need to fire.
Tricky part still would then be, that we also need to know what the starting velocity is at the time we start firing the thrusters (which depends on the altitude we start firing).
The core of my question:
I was hoping someone could help me to proceed with this analysis by giving their insights, I am sure there is already quite some knowledge on this topic.
I would also greatly appreciate some insights on other methods to determining the burn height and propellant mass.
Anyway, that was quite a long post. I would really appreciate the help, and thanks for your time and effort in advance!
Regards, Alex

How significant is the drag?

Congratulations on learning spaceflight and Python at the same time!  I haven't debugged it, but here are some alternate ways to leverage some conveniences of Python better https://pastebin.com/xLJ3MkA3 and you can use plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.1, hspace=0.1) before plotting to leave a little more room between the plots so we can see the labels better (0.1 is just a guess)

To the "core" of your question, you are looking for a closed-form expression for delta-v that includes the effects of drag? Yikes! This isn't 1940, why not just numerically integrate? scipy.integrate.solve_ivp?

Welcome to Space SE!  I've seen there are votes to close this question as it needs more focus. I've voted to keep it open as you're new here. I suggest you add one or two sentences at the top to narrow this post to one question. This means that folks can recognise other areas that might be causing difficulty. Keep all the rest of the post as context for the moment though you could add a heading or formatting to highlight the core subject matter .  You can always raise more questions in new posts, linking back to here, once you've got feedback on whatever is most important you to solve first.
